# Inject DbContextOptions vs DbContext in a repository EF Core

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have the StudentDbContext

```
public class StudentDbContext : DbContext
{
    public StudentDbContext()
    {
    }

    public StudentDbContext(DbContextOptions<StudentDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {

    }

    public virtual DbSet<Students> Students{ get; set; }

}
```

and then I have a repository and I try to understand what is the difference if I inject the StudentDbContext vs inject DbContextOptions

> Inject the DbContextOptions

```
class StudentRepository : IStudentRepository
{
    private readonly DbContextOptions<StudentDbContext> _context;

    public StudentRepository(DbContextOptions<StudentDbContext> context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
}
```

> Inject StudentDbContext

```
class StudentRepository : IStudentRepository
{
    private readonly StudentDbContext _context;

    public StudentRepository(StudentDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
}
```

Are there any advantages or disadvantages in each case?

Answer (score 0):

DbContextOptions class is used to create the options to be used by a DbContext. It configures the database (and other options) to be used for the database context. DbContext class contains DbSet properties for each entity in the model.
If you try to use DbContextOptions in a repository you will have no access to any model since it doesn't have them.

Answer (score 0):

`DbContextOptions` and `DbContextOptions<TContext>` have different use cases.

You need to inject `DbContextOptions` (generic or not) in subtypes of `DbContext`.
The `DbContextOptions` instance will contain the options that you have configured in the `Startup` class:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContextFactory<ConcreateDbContext>(
        options => options.UseSqlServer(@"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=Test")
    );
}
```

If your `DbContext` implementation is not supposed to be inherited from, you will inject in your `ConcreateDbContext` the generic version of options type `DbContextOptions<ConcreateDbContext>`, and this ensures that the correct options for the specific DbContext subtype are resolved from dependency injection. You can also, mark your `ConcreateDbContext` as sealed, as the class is not designed to be inherited from.

```cs
public sealed class ConcreateDbContext: DbContext
{
    public ConcreateDbContext(DbContextOptions<ConcreateDbContext> contextOptions)
        : base(contextOptions)
    {
    }
}
```

In case that you want to have a `DbContext` that is intended to be inherited from, you are supposed to expose a protected constructor which will take as a parameter the non-generic version of `DbContextOptions`.

```cs
public class BaseDbContext: DbContext
{
    protected BaseDbContext(DbContextOptions contextOptions)
        : base(contextOptions)
    {
    }
}
```

In case you want to have a `DbContext` that is intended to be both instantiated and inherited from, you will have two constructors, one taking the generic, and one the non-generic version of `DbContextOptions`.

And when you want to interact with the data in your database, you will inject the concrete `DbContext` implementation (in your case `StudentDbContext`).